# how to display users who browse articles in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to know who browse one post in wordpress。I dont know how to  display all users who browse one post in wordpress。Is there a plugin for this?

thanks

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What have you tried?)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-useronline/

Good luck! :)

Comment: You want the full code or a help? Based on the same logic as the plugin is written above, you can build your code. You can inspire from that code. Same sessions, logics must be used. It's a matter of what do you want here, users to work for you or get some help, directions, etc.